# Append parameters in Alamofire Swift

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have the follow array

```
let p = [
        "id": id
    ]
```

I would like to append these if they are added.

```
    if (minPriceUsed) {
        //p.add(["minPrice": minPriceText!])
    }
    if (maxPriceUsed) {
        //p.add(["maxPrice": maxPriceText!])
    }
```

However, I do not see anything for this array type to append, or add, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alamofire parameter is a **Dictionary** not an array.So you need to add new items like this

```
if (minPriceUsed) {
      p["minPrice"] = minPriceText!
}
if (maxPriceUsed) {
      p["maxPrice"]. = maxPriceText!
}
```

more info : https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#making-requests

Answer (score 3):

it's dictionary not array you need

```
var p = [
    "id": id
]
```

---

```
if minPriceUsed {
    p["minPrice"] = minPriceText!
}
```